# Is Solr complete re-index required when adding new products?

Tags: apache, solr

Suppose, I have 100 products in DB, I did the indexing and created the documents. Now they added 10 more products to the DB. Now, What should I do to update/add these 10 products with existing indexed document?
What I am doing is, deleting the existing documents and doing the indexing. I think this is not a proper way. Please guide me in this.

Note:  In between I am not changing anything in `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml`

Answer (score 2):

Just add new / modified documents to solr and that's it. There's no need to delete the entire index for one update. If document with id 1 has field `title` change from `foo` to `bar`, just add the document with the same `id` field to the index, keeping the unchanged fields to their old values (for example 'text':'old value' , 'date' : 'old date') and with the `title` field set to the new `foo` value. Solr (or rather solr and lucene) will take care of the rest.

Comment: Hi can we set cron job to do this? Any resource link?

Comment: resource or link for what exactly?

Comment: Here is one of the (many) links regarding solr updates https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#add.2Freplace_documents . AFAIK having a cron job reading the newest documents from the database and indexing them is perfectly acceptable